# Angular ng-repeat not functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to display JSON data to a view via an $http() call.  I am getting my data back, however, the ng-repeat is not displaying my data properly.  I am getting a console error stating "Error: $digest already in progress".

Another note is that the getRoundDetails() function is being called in the addRound() from the previous view's submit.

I am relatively new to using Angular and have never seen a $digest reference.  Please help.

Here is my controller.js:

```
statTrackerApp.controller('roundController',
    function($scope, $http, $window, $route) {
        $scope.newRound = {};
        $scope.savedRound = {};
        $scope.roundDetails = []; //I have tried {} as well with no success

        $scope.facilities = {};
        $scope.courses = {};
        $scope.tees = {};
        $scope.holes = {};

        ...

        $scope.addRound = function () {
            $http.post("/api/round/", $scope.newRound)
                .then(function (result) {
                    // Successful
                    //angular.copy(result.data, $scope.facilities);
                    //$window.location = "#/facilities";
                    $scope.savedRound = result.data;
                    $scope.getRoundDetails();
                    $window.location.href = '#/roundDetail';
                },
          function () {
              // Error
              alert("Could not save new round");
          });
        };
        $scope.getRoundDetails = function () {
            $http.get("/api/roundDetail/" + $scope.savedRound.roundId)
                .then(function (result) {
                    // Successful
                    //angular.copy(result.data, $scope.roundDetails);

                    $scope.roundDetails = result.data;
                },
                    function () {
                        // Error
                        alert("Could not load round details.");
                    });
        };
    });
```

Here are my 2 view wrappers:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRoundDetails()" ng-controller="roundController">
    <div ng-include="'app/partials/_roundDetails-form.html'"></div>
</form>


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRound()" ng-controller="roundController">
    <div ng-include="'app/partials/_round-form.html'"></div>
</form>
```

Here is the _roundDetails-form.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Round Details</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div>
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li ng-repeat="roundDetail in roundDetails">
                    {{roundDetail.roundDetailId}}
                </li>
            </ul>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is _round-form.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Round</h2>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="facility" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facility: </label></td>
                <td><select ng-change="getCourses(newRound.facilityId)" ng-model="newRound.facilityId" class="form-control" id="facility" required="required">
                        <option ng-repeat="facility in facilities" value="{{facility.facilityId}}">{{facility.name}}</option>
                    </select><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="course" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course: </label></td>
                <td><select ng-change="getTees(newRound.courseId)" ng-model="newRound.courseId" class="form-control" id="course" required="required">
                        <option ng-repeat="course in courses" value="{{course.courseId}}">{{course.name}}</option>
                    </select><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="tee" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tees: </label></td>
                <td><select ng-model="newRound.teeId" class="form-control" id="tee" required="required">
                        <option ng-repeat="tee in tees" value="{{tee.teeId}}">{{tee.name}}</option>
                    </select><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date: </label></td>
                <td><input type="date" ng-model="newRound.date" class="form-control" id="date" required="required" placeholder="Enter date." /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="official" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Is Official: </label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="newRound.isOfficial" class="form-control" id="official" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="holes" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Holes: </label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="newRound.holes" class="form-control" id="holes" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="hbh" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hole by Hole: </label></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="newRound.hbh" class="form-control" id="hbh" /><br /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="score" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Score: </label></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="newRound.TotalScore" class="form-control" id="score" value="0" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <input ng-click="getHoles(newRound.teeId)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Round" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I can add Json data if necessary.

Comment: You are calling like this `$scope.getRoundDetails();` and then                   `$window.location.href = '#/roundDetail';` If you do this, $scope will be destroyed. `roundDetails` will not be available.

Comment: What would be the best way to transfer data from Rounds to RoundDetails? I initially had the wrapper housing both forms but separated them to try to solve the issue.

Comment: @MTL323, good use case for angular-ui router and its state based routing to a nested view.

Comment: If roundDetails is separate page(i mean view), you can define template(html) and controller in your router configuration.If you have nested views, then you can go with ui-router.

Comment: To clarify, since RoundDetail is a child of Round, the most effective rounting would be angular-ui routing? If so, I will have to research this as I am not familiar with this solution to this point.

Comment: I am a bit confused because when the RoundDetails view rendered, I was able to gather data and copy to the $scope.roundDetails, which should just repopulate the object.  The object, at that point, was populated, just not able to display.